# Javascript loop with dynamic react component handler binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I am new to Javascript/ReactJs world. I am building a side nav. Below are some part of my code -

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Link from "./Link/Link";
    
class Sidebar extends Component {
    
    state = {
        dashboard: {
            name: "Dashboard",
            href: "#",
            active: true,
            svgPath: "M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6",
            children: []
        },
        team: {
            name: "Team",
            href: "#",
            active: false,
            svgPath: "M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Overflow",
                    href: "#",
                },
                {
                    name: "Members",
                    href: "#",
                },
                {
                    name: "Calender",
                    href: "#",
                },
                {
                    name: "Settings",
                    href: "#",
                }
            ]
        }
    } 

    navClickHandler = (e, key) => {
        console.log(e, key)
    }
    
    render() {
        let navLinks = [];
        for (const item in this.state) {
            navLinks.push(<Link key={item} navClicked={(e, item) => this.navClickHandler(e, item)} config={this.state[item]} />)
        }
    
        return (
            <div className="hidden bg-indigo-700 md:flex md:flex-shrink-0">
                <div className="flex flex-col w-64 border-r border-gray-200 pt-5 pb-4 bg-white overflow-y-auto">
                    <div className="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 px-4">
                        <img className="h-8 w-auto"
                                 src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-indigo-600-mark-gray-800-text.svg"
                             alt="Workflow" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-5 flex-grow flex flex-col">
                        <nav className="flex-1 px-2 space-y-1 bg-white" aria-label="Sidebar">
                            {navLinks}
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Sidebar;
```

How can I get the item value inside the `navClickedHandler` function -

```
let navLinks = [];
for (const item in this.state) {
    navLinks.push(<Link key={item} navClicked={(e, item) => this.navClickHandler(e, item)} config={this.state[item]} />)
}
```

Actually, I want to use that key(item) to check which of the side-nav is active. It will change the state object based on the click.

`console.log` in `nacClickHandler` is giving `undefined`.

Comment: Seems that you don't need `item` in `navClicked` handler. `navLinks.push(<Link key={item} navClicked={(e) => this.navClickHandler(e, item)} config={this.state[item]} />)`. This way you'll use `item` from a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `item` to `Link`, so you cannot get it as an argument back from the click event.

So change this:

```
navClicked={(e, item) => this.navClickHandler(e, item)}
```

to this:

```
navClicked={e => this.navClickHandler(e, item)}
```

Or, you can change your `<Link/>` component to something like this:

```
const Link = ({navClicked, item}) => (
  <div onClick={e => navClicked(e, item)}></div>
);
```

And pass `item` as a prop:

```
<Link key={item} item={item} navClicked={this.navClickHandler} config={this.state[item]} />
```

The second option is preferable since it allows you to pass the same function reference always, thus avoiding redundant renders (provided that `Link` is a `PureComponent`, or a functional component wrapped in `memo`)

Answer (score 1):

Hello other problems I see is that `key={item}` will be translated to `key=[object Object]` therefore your behaviour will fail due to the check `key1 !== key2` because the actual value will be  `[object Object]  !=== [object Object]` which fails.

An alternative I would suggest to either use some unique data `item.id` for instance or generate some using a basic package like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Back to your issue, in order to check which item is active I would suggest to you to do this:
`<Link key={item.id} .... active={state.selected.id === item.id}/>`